# Is there a verb for 'to make heroic'? Something like 'heroicised'?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

As per the title, is there a verb for 'to make heroic'? Something like 'heroicised'?

EDIT: For example, talking about how an author elevated a character to heroic status.

Comment: ... don't tell me that the quality you are adding is *heroicity* ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Lionize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lionize) (US spelling):

> To treat (a person) as if he were important, or a celebrity.

I've never heard "heroize" (given in other answers) used in the wild.

Answer (score 3):

The word is *heroize*, or alternatively spelled, *heroise.* The act is called *heroization.*

It means both, to:

> make someone into a hero

and

> treat someone as if they were a hero.

Comment: Reference links would be a good addition.

Answer (score 3):

The Oxford English Dictionary has entries for *heroify* and *heroize*, both with the meaning ‘to make a hero of’.

Answer (score 1):

you may use - "glorify" as a single word to mean "to make a hero"

Answer (score 0):

> As per the title, is there a verb for 'to make heroic'? Something like 'heroicised'?

I'm wondering what you mean by "to make heroic." From the pages of [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/heroic):

> **heroic** (*adj*)
>   • Having or displaying the character or attributes of a hero; daring;
>   intrepid; determined
>   • Of or pertaining to heroes; suitable to the character of a hero; bold, daring, noble, or commanding
>   • Showing extreme courage; especially of actions courageously undertaken in desperation as a last resort
>   • Having or displaying qualities appropriate for heroes
>   • Of behavior that is impressive and ambitious in scale or scope

So, what does *"to make heroic"* mean? That expression could mean, *to cause or impel someone to act in a more heroic manner*, although I think it usually means *to regard or deem as a hero*.

As for the latter interpretation, as others have said, you could use the word *heroize*, but, depending on your context, there might be better ways to say it – such as, "He was *heralded as a hero*." Without much additional context to draw from, it's hard to know if *heroize* would be your best option. When talking about an athlete, for example, instead of saying:

> He was *heroized* during the championship tournament.

it might be better to say:

> The championship tournament was his *[defining moment](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/defining+moment)*.

As for the former interpretation, that I wouldn't call that *heroization*; that sounds more like some kind of crisis training.

Comment: I have added some context to the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would favour *lionise* over *heroise* (adjust *-ise* to *-ize* if appropriate to the orthography in use), it's both more common and in my opinion more euphonious.

I'd also suggest considering *mythologise*, which is wider in meaning, but often appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

From the book "lies my history teacher told me" by Lloewen: He coins the term "heroification".

I think this might be what you're looking for...
see this too: [heroification](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84717)

Answer (score 0):

I watch a lot of cookery programmes on television, and at the moment I notice *hero* used as a verb in *Masterchef Australia*: 'this dish heroes the cheese' - in other words, the dish makes cheese the dominant element in the dish.

So here is my humble addition: *hero* as a verb.

Answer (score -2):

Heroic is defined as the adjective (description) of a hero, so ' the actions were heroic during the disaster'. 
From dictionary.com:

Related forms
he·ro·i·cal·ly, adverb

he·ro·i·cal·ness, 
he·ro·ic·ness, 
he·ro·ic·i·ty [heer-oh-is-i-tee]

non·he·ro·ic, adjective

non·he·ro·i·cal, adjective

non·he·ro·i·cal·ly, adverb

dots are to represent syllables.

Comment: None of those are a verb, which is explicitly what's being asked for....